# Exporting PLY file as NVM

Tags: python, blender, open3d

I'm using the following code to view ply that consists of pointclouds.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import webcolors
import seaborn as sns


input_file = "data/pointcloud.ply"
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file) # Read the point cloud
downpcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
r, g, b = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(sns.xkcd_rgb['indigo'])
downpcd.paint_uniform_color([r / 255, g / 255, b / 255])
# Visualize the point cloud within open3d
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])


point_cloud_in_numpy = np.asarray(pcd.points)

print(point_cloud_in_numpy.shape)
```

However is there any ways to export ply file to nvm file?

I tried to use blender but it throws the following error,

> NVMFileHandler.write_nvm_file(self,of,cameras,points) calib_mat =
> cameras[0].get_Calibration_mat() IndexError: list index out of range

How can I export the ply file to nvm?